# "File not found Exception" at runtime in Glassfish ESB 2.1

Tags: glassfish-esb

Good wishes of the day..!

In production we have Glassfish 2.1 server hosting ESB Applications in two instances  each under two Linux Boxes.  Functionality of the ESB app to takes client request and transform to destination, again receive the response and sent back to the client.

From past few days we are seeing "File not found Exception" in the logs throwing by WsdlQueryHelper of HTTP BC. We analyzed the logs and came to know that it is happening for only one instance (Instance 2 of Server 1), that to for few requests in that instance. We checked the service of that instance from SOAP tool and it is giving appropriate response, Understood that WsdlQueryHelper failed to process  few requests at runtime. Below exception details for the same in logs,

> *[#|2012-12-13T18:29:24.526+1100|FINE|sun-appserver2.1|com.sun.jbi.httpsoapbc.WsdlQueryHelper|_ThreadID=319;_ThreadName=httpWorkerThread-7092-0;ClassName=com.sun.jbi.httpsoapbc.WsdlQueryHelper;MethodName=;_RequestID=6fdd0535-24d4-4878-8c98-b48e2dea39eb;|init
>   query helper failed. javax.wsdl.WSDLException: WSDLException (at
>   /definitions/types/xsd:schema): faultCode=OTHER_ERROR: An error
>   occurred trying to resolve schema referenced at 'RouterSchema_v4.xsd',
>   relative to ''.: java.io.FileNotFoundException: This file was not
>   found:
>   file:/home/glassfish/GlassFishESBv21/glassfish/nodeagents/GLASSFISH-001-NA/GLASSFISH-001-instB/RouterSchema_v4.xsd
>           at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.parseSchema(WSDLReaderImpl.java:918)
>           at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.parseSchema(WSDLReaderImpl.java:678)
>           at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.parseTypes(WSDLReaderImpl.java:639)
>           at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.parseDefinitions(WSDLReaderImpl.java:339)
>           at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(WSDLReaderImpl.java:2324)
>           at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(WSDLReaderImpl.java:2288)
>           at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(WSDLReaderImpl.java:2341)
>           at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(WSDLReaderImpl.java:2362)
>           at com.sun.jbi.httpsoapbc.WsdlQueryHelper.(WsdlQueryHelper.java:105)
>           at com.sun.jbi.httpsoapbc.embedded.JAXWSGrizzlyRequestProcessor.processSynchronousQueryResource(JAXWSGrizzlyRequestProcessor.java:293)
>           at com.sun.jbi.httpsoapbc.embedded.JAXWSGrizzlyRequestProcessor.service(JAXWSGrizzlyRequestProcessor.java:217)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(DefaultProcessorTask.java:647)
>           at com.sun.jbi.httpsoapbc.embedded.JBIGrizzlyAsyncFilter.doFilter(JBIGrizzlyAsyncFilter.java:95)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.async.DefaultAsyncExecutor.invokeFilters(DefaultAsyncExecutor.java:175)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.async.DefaultAsyncExecutor.interrupt(DefaultAsyncExecutor.java:153)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.async.AsyncProcessorTask.doTask(AsyncProcessorTask.java:92)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.TaskBase.run(TaskBase.java:265)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.WorkerThreadImpl.run(WorkerThreadImpl.java:116)
>   Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: This file was not found:
>   file:/home/glassfish/GlassFishESBv21/glassfish/nodeagents/GFESB_ASPAC_001-NA/GFESB_ASPAC_001-instB/RouterSchema_v4.xsd
>           at com.ibm.wsdl.util.StringUtils.getContentAsInputStream(StringUtils.java:199)
>           at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.parseSchema(WSDLReaderImpl.java:840)
>           ... 17 more |#]*

Could you please help us to resolve the issue.

Regards,
Ram